# CakePHP - How to get request URL and client IP on model?

Tags: cakephp, model, request, ip

I would like to know, How to get request URL and client IP on model?

Thanks for any example.

class AccessLog extends AppModel {

```
public function writeLog() {
    //var_dump();
    $requestData['date_time'] = date(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT, strtotime("now"));
    $requestData['request_url'] = "http://www.gogle.com/";
    $requestData['ip'] = "192.168.0.1";
    $requestData['referral_url'] = "http://www.gogle.com/";
    $requestData['browser_info'] = "Browser info";
    $this->save($requestData);
}
```

Comment: Why you need `IP` in model?

Comment: Because of the i want log access into DB. I updated code above.

Comment: You have to write your code in your `AccessLogsController`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$requestData['ip'] = $this->RequestHandler->getClientIp();
```

Comment: It throws 
Fatal error: Call to a member function getClientIp() on a non-objec

Comment: Because you cannot access `$this->RequestHandler` in Model you have to use your code in controller.